# Find the largest $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $x \in \mathbb{N}$ the equation $16^x+10x-1 \equiv 0 \pmod d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I interpret this problem as being finding the $gcd$ of the set of numbers generated by that given sequence.

Checking by hand for a possible pattern in the sequence, I noticed instead that every term seemed to be divisible by $25$. Following though on that, I thought that proving $16^x -10x +1 \equiv 0 \mod25$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ would be sufficent. If that is proven, then proving that $25$ is maximal, and is therefore $d=25$, could follow from an easy proof by contradiction from the fact that the first term in the sequence is $25$.

The problem is, I can't think of any clever way to work this problem is $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$. Is there a reduction that makes this easier?

Comment: One way to work modulo $25$ is to write $$16^x = (3 \cdot 5 + 1)^x$$ Upon expanding with the binomial theorem, only two terms are left that aren't divisible by $25$.

Comment: This problem can also be interpreted as determining $d\in\mathbb N$ such that $\color{grey}\forall\,x\in\Bbb N$, $16^x+10x-1$ is divisible by $d$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x=1$ we have $16^x+10x-1=16+10-1=25$, so $d\mid25$ and $d\le25$.

So let's try to prove $25$ divides every term. Assume it holds for some $x$, then
$$16^{x+1}+10(x+1)-1=16(16^x+10x-1)-160x+16+10x+9\equiv-150x+25\equiv0$$
$\text{mod }25$, so it holds for every term and it's maximal.

Answer (score 0):

First, its obvious $d$ cannot be even, otherwise by the chinese remainder theorem we have, $16^x+10x-1\equiv 0 \pmod 2$ or $-1\equiv 0 \pmod 2$ a contradiction. So suppose $d$ is odd so that $gcd(2,d)=1$, then 
by Euler-Fermat theorem we have; $16^{\phi(d)}\equiv 1 \pmod d$ or $16^{\phi(d)}+10d-1\equiv 0 \pmod d$, now subtract this last equation from the given equation to get; 
$16^x-16^{\phi(d)}\equiv 10(d-x) \pmod d$. Now, at $x=d$, the last equation transforms to $16^{\phi(d)}-16^d \equiv 0 \pmod d$ or $\phi(d)\equiv d \pmod d$, which is not true for any integer $d$. Hence, there is no $d$ for which the proposed equation holds for ALL $x$ element of the natural numbers